# Test project does not reference any .NET Nuget adapter

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit-3.0

My test project has NUnit and NUnit3TestAdapter installed however the tests are not found in the test explorer.

When I show output from Tests in the debug window I see that there is no test available in my UnitTests.DLL

I can run the tests from Resharper.

[Update]

I closed and re-opened the solution the message from the Output Tests window is gone but the tests are still not discovered

I am running VS 16.8.0 Preview 3.1

Answer (score 1):

Tests became visible when I clicked the flask icon
[image: flask icon]

Comment: If your problem has been solved, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: SO requires me to wait 2 days